# Python WebSocket is not working on Raspbery

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, raspberry-pi

Running the server and client on mac with localhost everything works fine.

Running the python program (server) on the raspberry pi and try to access it using its url doesn't work.

Python Server:

```
class Strompreisgenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ws = websockets.serve(self.echo, 'localhost', 5001)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.ws)
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

    async def echo(self, websocket, path):
        async for message in websocket:
            print(message)
```

Javascript Client:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://www.tobiasschmocker.ch:5001");
```

While trying to instantiate the WebSocket the error *"WebSocket network error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused"* occurs in safari.

The Port 5001 is open on RPi. I also tried local IP. I forwarded the Port on my router but still nothing. If i trie other urls i get another error, so i suppose the url is correct but i have no rights somehow.

On my RPi i have ssh enabled, also php, apache, mysql and all the pip packages for my python server.

If you know, where the problem lies, i'd be happy to know. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please show how you use your Strompreisgenerator?

Comment: Can you please write what happens when you run `nc -v www.tobiasschmocker.ch 5001`

Comment: @YonatanKiron with `nc -v www.tobiasschmocker.ch 5001` i get: `nc: connect to www.tobiasschmocker.ch port 5001 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`

Comment: @RetoAebersold I create an instance of the Strompreisgenerator further down in the code. I run the py-File from the terminal: `python3 path/Strompreisgenerator.py` . There is also a MQTT-Clients publishing in the program. The MQTT-Broker runs on port 1883 on www.tobiasschmocker.ch and for now i publish on the topic "Sarah" using a cronjob. I hope this is not interfering with the websocket. MQTT works fine, but the websocket doesnt. I have this problem only if i run the program on the RPi - on my mac it works fine. I'll keep the program running if you want to try out the Websocket or MQTT.

Comment: @agittarius and when you run it from your RPi, using the Doman name, localhost, and 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @agittarius: But you run the event loop, right? `websocket.serve`does nothing until you start the asyncio event loop.

Comment: @Reto yes, as you can see now in the question, i start the event loop while instantiating the object - it works fine on my mac, so this should not be the error

Comment: @YonatanKiron: I new reinstalled my RPi with GUI to have a browser on it. I ran python-APP and js-Client both with localhost and there was no error on startup. But when i try to send a message i get this error: `WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.` Trying to reach it from my Macbook over local IP or url i still have the old error. Do i have to open up the port on the rpi somehow?

Comment: @agittarius that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out. If you  are connected to the RPi, via ssh, what `nc -v` returns. This command checks if the port is open, and will help us point the problem. Run the command from your RPi, and check if you get `connection refused` from there also. If yes, there is nothing that listens to the port. If no, the port is not open. From my experience, that looks like an application issue, and I would check if the app is actually listen to this port.

Comment: @YonatanKiron sorry for letting you wait so long. If i try it with www.tobiasschmocker.ch I get:
`nc: connect to www.tobiasschmocker.ch port 5001 (tcp) failed: Connection refused` and with localhost I get `Connection to localhost 5001 port [tcp/*] succeeded!`

Comment: @agittarius ok, that means that your port isn't forwarded right to your RPi. See, if you run it from your RPi and you get `Connection ... succceeded` that's mean that the app is ok, and listens to the port. but, because there is nothing that listens to the port over you domain, you get `Connection refused`. So as a conclusion, you need to check your routing/firewall/domain configs.

Answer (score 5):

**Now the websocket is running and available via url from external!**

Following is the solution for completeness. All I had to do is:

- **Update to Python Version 3.6**. The websockets package seems to work only from Python Version 3.6. Here's the tutorial I used to install Python 3.6 on my RPi: https://gist.github.com/dschep/24aa61672a2092246eaca2824400d37f
- **use** `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` as host within python. On `sudo netstat -lptu` in the RPi terminal, I could see that all the other ports (mqtt, ssh, etc) where set to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` so I just tried and it works.

Having set all that, the websocket is now running. Thanks to @YonatanKiron & @Reto!

Comment: Thank you for your message, effectively using 0.0.0.0 solved my problem.